# Using Time Travel doesn't work out for me as expected

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

By learning Snowflake I have done a few steps with the time travel of snowflake to undo
an update. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me, even tough I am taking the SQL commands directly from the tutorial:

At the beginning I am starting by changing a column by running the following update statement:

```
update trips set start_station_name = 'oops';
```

afther that I am running the following select statement, which is showing me, that the field was successfully updated to 'oops':

```
select
start_station_name as "station",
count(*) as "rides"
from trips
group by 1
order by 2 desc
limit 20;
```

Now the magic should happen by the following functionality of snowflake:

Normally we would need to scramble and hope we have a backup lying around.

In Snowflake, we can simply run a command to find the query ID of the last `UPDATE` command and store it in a variable named $QUERY_ID.

```
set query_id =
(select query_id from table(information_schema.query_history_by_session (result_limit=>5))
where query_text like 'update%' order by start_time limit 1);
```

Then the following query:

Use Time Travel to recreate the table with the correct station names:

```
create or replace table trips as
(select * from trips before (statement => $query_id));
```

Now, if I would run the select statement from above again, I should get the result with the old values in the column instead of the 'oops'.

Unfortunately, I am just receiving an error here saying, that the statement $query_id was not found.

How could I fix this kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what all may have happened, but it's possible the update statement isn't showing up in the last five in the session hisstorry. If you're using the Snowsight UI you can look in your query history and find the query ID for the update.

[image]

When you have the query ID, you can run this:

```
create or replace table trips as
(select * from trips before (statement => '2770de7a-0881-11ed-861d-0242ac120002'));
```

Replacing the query ID with yours of course.

By default, Snowflake has a retention policy of one day of time travel on a table. If the update happened longer ago than the retention period, this won't work. (For regular tables, there's an additional 7-day period of something called Failsafe, and Support can help recover that data by opening a case with them.)